# Random Number Generator in Java

Tags: java, random

I'm writing a program that will work like a magic 8 ball. It asks for a question and then prints a random response out of 20 that I've put in it. It doesn't show any errors in the coding, but when I run it the program works perfectly until the point where it would need to print the random response. This is a homework assignment so I'm not looking for someone to correct it, but I'm trying to figure out exactly how to get this to work. Thank you and I appreciate the help.

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class MagicBall
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please type in a question: ");
        double question = input.nextDouble();


        int number = (int)(Math.random() * 20);

        if (number == 0)
            System.out.println("As I see it, yes");

        if (number == 1)
            System.out.println("It is certain");

        if (number == 2)
            System.out.println("It is decidedly so");

        if (number == 3)
            System.out.println("Most likely");

        if (number == 4)
           System.out.println("Outlook good");

        if (number == 5)
            System.out.println("Signs point to yes");

        if (number == 6)
            System.out.println("Without a doubt");

        if (number == 7)
            System.out.println("Yes");

        if (number == 8)
            System.out.println("Yes – definitely");

        if (number == 9)
            System.out.println("You may rely on it");

        if (number == 10)
            System.out.println("Reply hazy, try again");

        if(number == 11)
            System.out.println("Ask again later");

        if (number == 12)
            System.out.println("Better not tell you now");

        if (number == 13)
            System.out.println("Cannot predict now");

        if (number == 14)
            System.out.println("Concentrate and ask again");

        if (number == 15)
            System.out.println("Don't count on it");

        if (number == 16)
            System.out.println("My reply is no");

        if (number == 17)
            System.out.println("My sources say no");

        if (number == 18)
            System.out.println("Outlook not so good");

        if (number == 19)
            System.out.println("Very doubtful");
    }
}
```

Comment: This is why god invented switch statements.

Comment: ... or array lookups :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works for me, but it forces you to input a double (e.g. 123.456).  You should change:

```
double question = input.nextDouble();
```

to:

```
String question = input.nextLine();
```

Also, you may want to use a switch statement instead of all those ifs.

Comment: Thank you. I changed it to String instead of double and it works. And I was going to use switch statements but this is the first homework for the class and I don't want to use anything that hasn't been covered yet.

Answer (score 6):

```
double question = input.nextDouble();
```

What makes you think the question would be a floating point number?

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure why I used double. I changed it to String and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Apache commons is very helpfull:

```
RandomUtils.nextInt(maxVal);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `int number = (int)(Math.random() * 20);`

Replace with `int number = new Random().nextInt(20);`

See [http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt(int)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29)

Comment: ...Which, in this context, does exactly the same thing?